# Changing Permalinks for Default Post type to reflect navigation

Tags: posts, permalinks, url-rewriting

I have a particular issue with setting the permalink structure for "posts" on my website. Right now, I have the default "posts" page living under

www.mywebsite.com/news-events/current-news/

I'd like the links for each post to parent under the URL structure, so they will read like such

www.mywebsite.com/news-events/current-news/article-1
www.mywebsite.com/news-events/current-news/article-2

Right now, they only show as such
www.mywebsite.com/article-1
www.mywebsite.com/article-2

Any ideas how I can repath the posts to reflect my URL structure? I only want to change it for the default posts, as I have CPTs that do not need to have the base URL rewritten to add "/news-events/current-news/", which is why I can't use the "Custom Structure" setting under "Permalinks"

Thanks,
Devin

Answer (score 1):

If I remember right you can simply go to `Settings` > `Permalinks` and change `Custom Structure` to `/news-events/current-news/%postname%/`.

Comment: But that will change the URL rewrite structure for the CPT I have added to the site as well. I'm just looking to change the default posts.

Comment: Hmmmm... I am not sure how CPT plays with it, since they have bunch of rewrite-related setting in registration.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-registering default post type and add a rewrite slug with _builtin param set to false.

I think it should work for you.